# Perform action after if statement CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I had a problem with checking continuously page for change of attribute but I did it.
Now my main code looks like this:

```
casper.thenOpen('pageurl', function() { 
    this.then(function () {
        function checkReload()
        {
            var cur = this.getElementAttribute("classname", "attr");
            if (cur == "target") {here
                return; // finished
            }
            else
            {
                this.echo(cur);
            }
            this.reload();
            this.wait(1, checkReload); // check again in a second
        }
        this.then(checkReload);         
    }).thenEvaluate(function(){
        this.click("#new_add");
        this.echo("done567");   
        this.then.waitForSelector(".cartGdList",
            function pass () {
                this.click("...");
                this.echo("done8");
                this.then(function () {
                    this.waitForSelector(".cart_s_Box",
                        function pass () {
                            this.click("#js_upFormBtn");
                            this.echo("step4");
                            var end = new Date().getTime();
                            var time = end - start;
                            this.echo('time: ' + time + 'ms*');
                        },
                        function fail () {
                            this.echo('fail');
                        }
                    );
                });
            },
            function fail () {
                this.echo('fail');
            }
        );
    });
});
```

And after if statement would be OK `if(cur == "target")`
I want to perform this code:

```
this.click("#new_add");
this.echo("done567");   
this.then.waitForSelector(".cartGdList",
    function pass () {
        this.click("...");
        this.echo("done8");
        this.then(function () {
            this.waitForSelector(".cart_s_Box",
                function pass () {
                    this.click("#js_upFormBtn");
                    this.echo("step4");
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = end - start;
                    this.echo('time: ' + time + 'ms*');
                },
                function fail () {
                    this.echo('fail');
                }
            );
        });
    },
    function fail () {
        this.echo('fail');
    }
);
```

How can I do this, I tried to put this on `thenEvaluate` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary nesting, but first things first. You want to execute some code in an `if`-branch. Ok, then put the code in that `if`-branch.

```
casper.thenOpen('pageurl', function() { 
    this.then(function () {
        function checkReload()
        {
            var cur = this.getElementAttribute("classname", "attr");
            if (cur == "target") {
                this.click("#new_add");
                this.echo("done567");
                // ...
                return; // stop recursion
            }
            else
            {
                this.echo(cur);
            }
            this.reload();
            this.wait(1, checkReload); // check again in a second
        }
        this.then(checkReload);
        // ...
```

If you don't want so much indentation, you can also put the code in a function.

```
function myIfBranch(){
    this.click("#new_add");
    this.echo("done567");
    // ...
}

casper.thenOpen('pageurl', function() { 
    this.then(function () {
        function checkReload()
        {
            var cur = this.getElementAttribute("classname", "attr");
            if (cur == "target") {
                myIfBranch.call(this);
                return; // stop recursion
            }
            else
            {
                this.echo(cur);
            }
            this.reload();
            this.wait(1, checkReload); // check again in a second
        }
        this.then(checkReload);
        // ...
```

As for the unnecessary nesting. Remember that both `then*` and `wait*` functions are actually asynchronous step functions and both behave in the same asynchronous way. Here is a cleaned up example:

```
function myIfBranch(){
    this.click("#new_add");
    this.echo("done567");   
    this.waitForSelector(".cartGdList",
        function pass () {
            this.click("...");
            this.echo("done8");
            this.waitForSelector(".cart_s_Box",
                function pass () {
                    this.click("#js_upFormBtn");
                    this.echo("step4");
                    var end = new Date().getTime();
                    var time = end - start;
                    this.echo('time: ' + time + 'ms*');
                },
                function fail () {
                    this.echo('fail');
                }
            );
        },
        function fail () {
            this.echo('fail');
        }
    );
}

casper.thenOpen('pageurl', function() {
    function checkReload() {
        var cur = this.getElementAttribute("classname", "attr");
        if (cur == "target") {
            myIfBranch.call(this);
            return; // finished
        }
        else
        {
            this.echo(cur);
        }
        this.reload();
        this.wait(1, checkReload); // check again in a second
    }
    this.then(checkReload);
```

---

Remember that `this` inside of `casper.evaluate` and `casper.thenEvaluate` doesn't refer to `casper`, but to `window`. There simply is no `window.click`, `window.echo` or `window.then` function. Also, `this.then.waitForSelector(...)` doesn't make sense.

Comment: 'this.click("#js_upFormBtn");'
'this.echo("step4");'
There is show time of execution function but it doesnt echo time

Comment: sorry i just need to initalize variable not in casper function. thank you for help